# What is the use of gold in Talisman?

Tags: talisman

I'm playing the game Talisman and have earned around 6 gold. However, this is my second game and not even once I have seen an opportunity where we can use this gold. Is the gold of any use at all in this entire game?

Googling doesn't show anything related to gold for Talisman. Their wiki just makes a mention of it "you can exchange a bag of gold card for an actual gold if you have XYZ talisman". But nowhere it is explained *what* the gold actually does.

Answer (score 2):

Gold can be used for the purchase of game items, which can have a variety of effects. One needs to land on a space that specifically permits the use of gold or draw a card that permits you to use gold.

In the base game the uses for gold are somewhat limited, you can visit the Village and see the Blacksmith to purchase items from the purchase deck, such as a sword or a shield. Or you may draw the Pedlar or Market cards from the Adventure deck, both of which permit you to purchase items, including the Mule follower.

The expansions create additional places to buy things, especially the City expansion, which lets your gold really go to work in the form of services, mounts, magic items, pets, and more.